# Replacing the image by detecting the window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying load different images by detecting browser siz via JQuery. Implemented code is as follows,

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        var w_size = $(window).width();
        var img_src = $("img").attr("src");

        if (w_size < 400) {
            var new_s_image = img_src.replace(".", "_s.");
            $("img").attr("src",new_s_image);
        }else if (w_size < 780){
            var new_m_image = img_src.replace(".", "_m.");
            $("img").attr("src",new_m_image);
        }
    });
```

Now the issue is each time when I resize the window it's apending the "_s." or "_m." eg: **images/image_m_m_m.jpg**. I need to append the "_s." or "_m." characheter only once even though user resized the window countless times.

Comment: Use a setTimeout or CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there are css alternatives, as you have asked for a jQuery solution here is mine.

This code will handle multiple images and another condition could be added without too much bother.

The code is:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("img").each(function() {
        var w_size = $(window).width();
        var img_src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_m", "").replace("_s", "");
        var new_image = (w_size < 400) ? img_src.replace(".", "_s.") : (w_size < 780) ? new_image = img_src.replace(".", "_m.") : img_src;
        $(this).attr("src", new_image);
    });
});
```

And you can see this working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeteUh/fSqZK/)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a number of people would suggest CSS based solution which can be a good alternative.

**In the case that you still prefer to use jQuery**, you'd need to modify a few things:

1. **Give a suffix for normal state on your `img src`**

   For example: myimage_n.jpg
2. **Change the way you update the file name.**

   Instead of just replacing a dot with new characters `img_src.replace(".", "_s.")`,
   you can do this instead:

   ```
   trimmedSrc = myImageSrc.substr(0, myImageSrc.length - 5);
   var newSrc = trimmedSrc + 'm.jpg';
   myImage.attr("src", newSrc);
   ```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/wvyF6/

**Cleaned up code:** http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/wvyF6/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change your images every time the size of the browser has changed. You might want to adopt the *responsive* way of handling images size.

For example, the following example will make all your images responsive :

```
img {  
    height: auto;  
    max-width: 100%;   
}
```

Changing the image in the `src` attribute is overkill because at the end, it will cause way too much bandwidth consumption due to the fact that every single image is going to be reloaded. Plus as you will not have to deal with multiple versions of your images, this will save you a *lot* of time during your development.

Answer (score 0):

for your images use extensions as '_s.' and '_m.' for particular  and normal image as '_n.' if you want to replace then you can replace '_n.' with '_m.' or '_s.' and  they will not be appended again and again

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w_size = $(window).width();
    var img_src = $("img").attr("src");

    if (w_size < 400) {
        var new_s_image = img_src.replace("_n.", "_s.");
        $("img").attr("src",new_s_image);
    }else if (w_size < 780){
        var new_m_image = img_src.replace("_n.", "_m.");
        $("img").attr("src",new_m_image);
    }else if (w_size > 780){
        var new_m_image = img_src.replace("_m.", "_n.");
        var new_m_image = new_m_image.replace("_s.", "_n.");
        $("img").attr("src",new_m_image);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just add a cover image.

```
html {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use media queries to control what image version is currently visible. Consider the following example (I denoted small images with class `s`, and normal with `m`):

CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .s {display: block;}
    .m {display: none;}
}
@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
    .m {display: block;}
    .s {display: none;}
}
```

And jQuery fallback for IE<9:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 400) {
        $('body').addClass('small');
    }
    else if (width > 400) {
        $('body').removeClass('small');
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KGdyD/

In HTML you would have two images but only one will be visible in at time.